# Alternative method for using DISTINCT in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I retrieved records from Sphinx index through DISTINCT method using sphinx for large number of records...For the backup I'm going to retrieve data from mySQL for bulk records..

Is the same DISTINCT query works well for the mySQL table also..Or is there any other way for retrieving data from mySQL instead of DISTINCT for getting data from large data table without time delay...

Comment: The title says its a question about an alternative for DISTINCT, yet you appear to say you are using DISTINCT. If you are using DISTINCT, what precisely are you asking for? What is the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

If indexed, there isn't a difference between distinct and group by, some would argue that Distinct doesn't have to sort, however you can get this as well with the group by, if you  order by null in mysql, so I would say they aren't different at all.

However, perhaps I am missing the question all together.

Comment: Actually, I'm using DISTINCT in Sphinx for retrieving bulk of records.. IF i'm moving to mySQL and using DISTINCT in a table with huge records,It's getting time delay...So is there any other method to retrieve data in mySQL instead of DISTINCT for fast querying..

Comment: Could you show the query? sometimes adding in another index can increase the performance. Nothing knowing the query  but this might help: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11426